# Format a java.sql.Timestamp into UTC format for a JSON object

Tags: java

I have a java.sql.Timestamp object which is already in the GMT timezone.
When I print the Timestamp object, it shows like:
2016-11-28 10:49:27.0

I want to format it as:
2016-11-28T10:49:27.000Z

I tried Joda DateTime conversion like:

```
public static synchronized String utcFormat(long longValue)
{
    DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( longValue, DateTimeZone.UTC );
    return dateTimeUtc.toString();
}
```

But it returned a String adding 6 hours like:
2016-11-28T16:49:27.000Z

I don't want those 6 hours added. What do I do?

Comment: Time without time zone assumed to be local.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of toString, try toGMTString()